# Regular Expression in javascript for '45 minutes'

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a text box entry to be in the below format using javascript,

format to be validated: 45 minutes.

Validate that it should accept any numbers space minutes.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not intended to fulfill your need of free coding services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you I guess.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Search for 45 minutes in the text in the next paragraph:</p>

<p id="p01">45 minutes</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    text = document.getElementById("p01").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = /[0-9]{2}\sminutes/.exec(text);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here `[0-9]{2}` means that allow any number with two digits. `\s` means whitespace character and `minutes` is the text you want to be found in it.

If you want more basic information on regex expressions, you can find it here: [Regex Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)